# How to create EXCEL and WORD file using SuiteScript 2.0?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I'm using HTML Suitelet to create Word and Excel, I'm able to create CSV and PDF files but I am unable to create a Word or Excel. How do I do it?

```
file.create({name:'testinvoice.pdf',fileType:file.Type.PDF, contents:pdffile.getContents()});
```

Comment: Hi ,

Could you let me know if you are able to solve this. I am facing same issue. WORD file is getting created but its giving error at the time of opening. 
Here is my sample code
```
/**
*@NApiVersion 2.x
*@NScriptType ScheduledScript
*/
define(['N/file'],
function(file) {
function execute(context) {

// Create a file containing text
var fileObj = file.create({
name: 'test.docx',
fileType: file.Type.WORD,
contents: 'Hello'
});

var fileContent=fileObj.getContents({
});
log.debug('Contents',fileContent);

return{
execute:execute
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the file.Type enum in the help center. file.Type.WORD and file.Type.EXCEL are both supported, but your file.Create may be failing because the contents may not be create. I think this stack overflow question will be helpful with creating an XLS file: [Create Excel File in NetSuite's SuiteScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262020/create-excel-file-in-netsuites-suitescript)